# Extracting a text backwards from a selected character

Tags: grep

I have a file with following lines:

```
handleNewConnection:: User langfordm@system.com has 2 active nodes
handleNewConnection:: User bas102@system.com has 2 active nodes
handleNewConnection:: User bah001@system.com has 2 active nodes
handleNewConnection:: User mattleg@system.com has 2 active nodes
```

System has to look for "@" (selected character) and then to extract the string backwards the "@" sign. As you notice it can contain either numeric or alphabetic characters and the length is not constant.

With  `grep -o '[^"]@' /tmp/has2.txt`

I get:

```
m@
2@
1@
g@
```

1) Does anyone know if it is possible to get a second text file so in this way?

```
langfordm
bas102
bah001
mattleg
```

2) Does anyone know if I can use the names generated in 1) individually as an input for another process?

Comment: Thanks guys!!!! All these solutions are excelent for me!! You really helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` with PCRE (`-P`):

```
$ grep -Po '.*\s\K[^@]+(?=@)' file.txt
langfordm
bas102
bah001
mattleg
```

Or with GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed -r 's/.*\s([^@]+)@.*/\1/' file.txt 
langfordm
bas102
bah001
mattleg
```

You can obviously use the result in another process, it depends on how the next process takes input. Depending on that, you can create an array or pass the result directly on the STDIN of the next process.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches. The easiest is to use this Regular Expression pattern match

```
grep -io '[a-z0-9_.]*@[a-z0-9_.]*'
```

This will match and print the longest string comprising

- Zero or more (`*`) of case-insensitive characters in the ranges `a-z` or `0-9` or `_` or `.`
- precisely one `@`
- Zero or more (`*`) of case-insensitive characters in the ranges `a-z` or `0-9` or `_` or `.`

And then split off the `@domain` part

```
cut -d@ -f1
```

So the full line would be

```
grep -io '[a-z0-9_.]*@[a-z0-9_.]*' /tmp/file.txt | cut -d@ -f1
```

---

The other approach is to use a look-ahead PCRE that allows `grep` to print the username part of your `username@domain` pattern in one step. This is much harder to get right but it removes the need for the `cut` in the example above

```
grep -Pio '\S+(?=@\S+)'
```

This means

- Match one or more (`+`) non-space characters (`\S`)
- That are followed by the pattern `@` and one or more (`+`) non-space characters (`\S`)

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy with `P`erl compatible option:

```
grep -Po '\w+(?=@)' file
```

where `\w` match any word character, and `(?=...)` is so called *look ahead* regexp.

Output:

```
langfordm
bas102
bah001
mattleg
```

Answer (score 0):

With any version of `sed`, using basic regular expressions:

```
sed -e 's/.* \([^@]\+\)@.*/\1/' /tmp/has2.txt
```

As for your second question, you can **always** use data typed or extracted or generated in any manner as input to another process, as long as:

1. it's in a format that the other process can work with (or can be transformed into that format with `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, and/or the other usual tools)
2. the other process is capable of taking input either from stdin or
   from an arbitrary file or file(s) - i.e. isn't hard-coded to take its input only from one specific file in a specific location....and even then, if you create/overwrite that specific file so that it contains your data it will still work.

This is the beauty of unix and the small-tools approach - it encourages you to think in a data-centric way (where the data is yours to do what you want with, using the tools of your choice including custom-written tools) rather than an application-centric way (where the data belongs to the magic black-box application and you can only manipulate or interact with the data via that particular application).

Just as importantly, it encourages developers, including application developers, to think in that same data-centric way.  And users to think of it as a bug and an infringement of their rights when app developers thwart their needs by attempting to lock up the users' data in their application.